# How to Select one element from a linq multiple join table?

Tags: c#, linq

```
var queryInfo = (from p in table1
                 join q in table2 on p.TABLEID equals q.USERNAME
                 join b in table3 on p.ORIGINAL_USER equals b.USERNAME
                 where p.NAME == IdVal
                 select new 
                        { 
                            p.NAME,
                            p.ID,
                            p.EXCHANGE,
                            p.CREATION,
                            q.USERNAME,
                            q_email = q.EMAIL,
                            q_fullname = q.FULL_NAME,
                            b_email = b.EMAIL,
                            p.ORIGINAL_USER,
                            b_fullname = b.FULL_NAME
                        });

Name = queryInfo.ToList().ElementAt(0).ToString();
ID = queryInfo.ToList().ElementAt(1).ToString();
exchange = queryInfo.ToList().ElementAt(2).ToString();
Creation = queryInfo.ToList().ElementAt(3).ToString();
AUsername = queryInfo.ToList().ElementAt(4).ToString();
AEmail = queryInfo.ToList().ElementAt(5).ToString();
AFullName = queryInfo.ToList().ElementAt(6).ToString();
EEmail = queryInfo.ToList().ElementAt(7).ToString();
EUsername = queryInfo.ToList().ElementAt(8).ToString();
EFullName = queryInfo.ToList().ElementAt(9).ToString();
```

The query is correct and working, I'm having problem trying to select and assign one to each declared variable.

I tried

```
queryInfo.ToList().ElementAt(0).ToString();
```

but this is not working. What is the proper syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom class so you can map your resut into

class:

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string exchange { get; set; }
    public string Creation { get; set; }
    public string AUsername { get; set; }
    public string AEmail { get; set; }
    public string AFullName { get; set; }
    public string EEmail { get; set; }
    public string EUsername { get; set; }
    public string EFullName { get; set; }
}
```

mapping:

```
User result = (from p in table1
                    join q in table2 on p.TABLEID equals q.USERNAME
                    join b in table3 on p.ORIGINAL_USER equals b.USERNAME
                    where p.NAME == IdVal
                    select new User()
                    {
                        Name = p.NAME,
                        ID = p.ID,
                        exchange = p.EXCHANGE,
                        Creation = p.CREATION,
                        AUsername = q.USERNAME,
                        AEmail = q.EMAIL,
                        AFullName = q.FULL_NAME,
                        EEmail = b.EMAIL,
                        EUsername = p.ORIGINAL_USER,
                        EFullName = b.FULL_NAME
                    }).FirtstOrDefault();
```

Comment: is there any other way aside from a custom class? this is a company program that is massive and have many queries, and what they previously did was declare as string and then assign like this 'assigned = queryAssigned.USERNAME;'. But that works because its taking from a single table and mine is multiple join table

Comment: @CodingNeeded anonymous types

Answer (score 1):

### First some background information

Your code is very inefficient.

`queryInfo` is an `IQueryable<...>`, meaning that it holds a query: the **potential to fetch some data**. It does not hold the data itself.

For this, the IQueryable holds an `Expression` and a `Provider`. The Expression represents the query in some generic format. The Provider knows who should execute this query (usually a database management system) and what language is used to communicate with this DBMS.

As long as you concatenate LINQ methods that return `IQueryable<TResult>`, only the Expression changes. The query is not executed, there is no communication with the DBMS. Concatenating this kind of LINQ methods is efficient.

IQueryable also implements IEnumerable. This means, that to execute the query and to enumerate the fetched sequence, at its lowest level you use `GetEnumerator()` to get the enumerator, and repeatedly call `MoveNext() / Current` to access the enumerated element:

```
IQueryable<TResult> query = dbContext.Students.Where(...).OrderBy(...);

// execute the query:
using (IEnumerator<TResult> enumerator = query.GetEnumerator())
{
    // and enumerate the fetched data:
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        // There is another element, process it:
        TResult fetchedElement = enumerator.Current;
        ProcessFetchedElement(fetchedElement);
    }
}
```

Well, this is a lot of code. Usually we use high level methods, which deep inside will call `GetEnumerator() / MoveNext() / Current`:

```
// execute the query and process the fetched data:
foreach (TResult fetchedElement in query)
{
    ProcessFetchedElement(fetchedElement);
}
```

All LINQ methods that return `IQueryable<...>` will not execute the query. The other LINQ methods (= the ones that return `List<TResult>, TResult, Boolean`, etc, anything not IQueryable) will call foreach or deep inside `GetEnumerator / MoveNext / Current`. These other methods will contact the database to execute the query.

### What does this have to do with my question?

Let's look at your code:

```
var queryInfo = ...
// queryInfo is an IQueryable. The query is not executed yet!

Name = queryInfo.ToList().ElementAt(0).ToString();
// ToList will execute the query and put all data in a List,
// from this List you take the first element and call ToString()

ID = queryInfo.ToList().ElementAt(1).ToString();
// ToList will execute the query again and put all data in a second List,
// from this List you take the second element and call ToString()
```

etc. You execute the query 10 times. You join the three tables 10 times, you keep only the one with p.Name equal to IdVal and send the remaining data to your process. You do this 10 times.

It would be much more efficient to do this only once:

```
// execute the query once and put all fetched data in a List
var fetchedData = queryInfo.ToList();

// access the fetched data. Since it is a List, we can use indexes
Name = fetchedData[0].ToString();
Id = fetchedData[1].ToString();
exchange = fetchedData[2].ToString();
Creation = fetchedData[3].ToString();
```

### I don't think that is what you want.

If I look closer at your query, then I see that you join three tables:

```
var queryInfo = (from p in table1
             join q in table2 on p.TABLEID equals q.USERNAME
             join b in table3 on p.ORIGINAL_USER equals b.USERNAME
```

From the joined table (=sequence of rows), you keep only those rows that have `p.Name == idVal`:

```
where p.NAME == IdVal
```

There might be one such element, there might be more, or maybe none.

From each remaining row, you make one new object:

```
select new 
{ 
    p.NAME,
    p.ID,
    p.EXCHANGE,
    ...
});
```

As said before: the result is a query. The query represents the potential to fetch a sequence of objects with properties `Name, Id, Exchange, ...`.

**I think, that you want the Name / Id / Exchange / etc from the first element of the sequence**

If that is the case, we don't have to fetch all elements, we only need to fetch the first element (if there is one)

```
var queryInfo = ...

// execute the query, and ask only for the first element.
// In SQL this is something like SELECT TOP 1 ... FROM ...
var fetchedElement = queryInfo.FirstOrDefault();
```

Now if your query yields one or more elements, you will have only the first one. However, if your query results in an empty sequence, fetchedElement will be null

```
if (fetchedElement != null)
{
    // There is an element with Name == IdVal
    Name = fetchedElement.Name;
    Id = fetchedElement.Id;
    ...
}
else
{
    // There is no such element; TODO: report to operator?
}
```

Be aware, that it if the query yields more than one element, it is not guaranteed what the first element of your sequence might be. Therefore, if you expect that in some cases there might be more than one element, consider to order the sequence, so the first element is defined. For instance order by ascending creation date. Sometimes the DBMS does not accept a `FirstOrDefault` of an unordered sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Materialize query via `FirstOrDefault()` and retrieve property values:

```cs
var queryInfo = 
    (from p in table1
    join q in table2 on p.TABLEID equals q.USERNAME
    join b in table3 on p.ORIGINAL_USER equals b.USERNAME
    where p.NAME == IdVal
    select new 
    { 
        p.NAME,
        p.ID,
        p.EXCHANGE,
        p.CREATION,
        q.USERNAME,
        q_email = q.EMAIL,
        q_fullname = q.FULL_NAME,
        b_email = b.EMAIL,
        p.ORIGINAL_USER,
        b_fullname = b.FULL_NAME
    })
    .FirstOrDefault();

Name = queryInfo?.NAME;
ID = queryInfo?.ID.ToString();
exchange = queryInfo?.EXCHANGE;
Creation = queryInfo?.CREATION.ToString();
AUsername = queryInfo?.USERNAME;
AEmail = queryInfo?.q_email;
AFullName = queryInfo?.q_fullname;
EEmail = queryInfo?.b_email;
EUsername = queryInfo?.ORIGINAL_USER;
EFullName = queryInfo?.b_fullname;
```